# Spring hibernate @manyToMany relation with @jsonView infinite recursion

Tags: hibernate, spring-boot, jackson

Im having issues with spring and jackson when i try to serialize them
I have two classes

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "conditions")
@Data
@JsonInclude(Include.NON_EMPTY)
@NoArgsConstructor
public class Condition implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -2917417625227297889L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = javax.persistence.GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name="nId")
    @JsonView(View.Public.class)
    private Integer id;


    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "conditions")
    @JsonView(View.Public.class)
    private Set<Rule> rules = new HashSet<Rule>(0);

    public Condition(int conditionId) {
        this.id = conditionId;
    }

}
```

and

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "tblComplianceRules")
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
public class Rule implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -4443637570696913241L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = javax.persistence.GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(nullable = false)
    @JsonView(View.Public.class)
    private Integer id;

    @Column
    @JsonView(View.Public.class)
    @NotEmpty
    private String name;


    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinTable(name = "tblComplianceRulesConditions", catalog = "swat", joinColumns = {
            @JoinColumn(name = "ruleId", nullable = false, updatable = false) }, inverseJoinColumns = {
                    @JoinColumn(name = "conditionId", nullable = false, updatable = false) })
    @JsonView(View.Public.class)
    private Set<Condition> conditions = new HashSet<Condition>();

    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "rules")
    @JsonBackReference
    @JsonView(View.Internal.class)
    private Set<CompliancePolicy> policies = new HashSet<CompliancePolicy>(0);

    public Rule(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }


}
```

Also ill post the View class

```
public class View {

    public static class Public {
    }

    public static class Internal extends Public {
    }

}
```

what im trying to achieve is that the response im sending to the client will not send unnecessary data, but im keep getting the error in my title...

i was able to resolve this by not using the @JsonView and using the @JsonBackReference but its not what i want...

As requested im attaching the response

```
@GetMapping(value = "/api/condition")
    @JsonView(View.Internal.class)
    public ResponseEntity<?> getConditions(Principal user) {
        if (user != null) {
            log.debug("Getting conditions for user: " + user.getName());
        } else {
            log.error("Warning user is not defined");
            return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED).build();
        }
        try {
            List<Condition> conditions = conditionService.getConditionsByOrderById();
            return ResponseEntity.ok().body(conditions);
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            log.error("Could not fetch condition from tblComplianceConditions: " + ExceptionUtils.getRootCauseMessage(ex), ex);
            return ResponseEntity.badRequest().body(ExceptionUtils.getRootCauseMessage(ex));
        }

    }
```

Comment: In each class i have other fields which i removed for sake of bravity

Comment: And what json view do you return in response?

Comment: @SergVasylchak i added the response

Comment: Check this article https://vladmihalcea.com/the-best-way-to-use-the-manytomany-annotation-with-jpa-and-hibernate/

Comment: @AvijitBarua thanks but i dont have an issue with the mapping only with the serialization

Comment: @naoru Can you post your error trace please?

Comment: @naoru Have you solved your issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found it easier to go with @JsonIgnore
for the properties that i needed I added a @transient field and added it there.